# Change Maven project name in eclipse's tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I've got a maven project named `Project` that has the following config to change the compilation name:
`<build><finalName>ProjectName</finalName></build>`
but when I try to deploy it on the eclipse's tomcat, the name of the project and therefore the context path is still `/Project`
Does anyone knows how to change this so that the path would be `/ProjectName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you want,
Right click on your project, -> Properties
Then on the left go into Web Project Settings -> Change the context root with your 'ProjectName'
Hope that's help

Comment: It worked indeed. Do you know which file is affected by that change? that would be quite helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a configuration file in eclipse : workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/publish/publish.dat